# Custom permission/restriction with DJANGO REST ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to restrict users to have only limited access/permissions in create or destroy method. Here is the scenario, a user, with admin role can do anything (create, get, update, delete), where as an ordinary user(customer) can only perform those allowed actions(create, get, delete) to its related model. My model looks like this

```
class Material(models.Model):
      ingredient  = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

class UserMaterialAllow(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
      material = models.ForeignKey('Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is how I added a custom restriction

```
/views/material.py

class MaterialView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset=Material.objects.all()
      serializer-class = MaterialSerializer

      def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          if(not app_admin(request.user)): // the user is not admin
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)// this will forbid non admin user
```

in MateralView, a user cant access if it is not an admin. What I need is, if the user is not an admin, just allow them to perform action but limited only the the `material belongs to them`

```
    app_admin implemtation


    `def app_admin(user):
         if user.user_is_admin:
             return True
         if user.is_superuser:
             return True
         return False
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django roles to define roles for the user and limit access to the page using the role and set permissions at the view level.  These links might be helpful

https://medium.com/djangotube/django-roles-groups-and-permissions-introduction-a54d1070544
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/